# Finding source of focus event on a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

I have a bunch of textareas and selectboxes in my view. All these have proper tab indexes for keyboard navigation. 
What is happening is that on load of this view, the last of the textareas is getting focus from somewhere and the view scrolls to that. Im not able to detect where is it getting focus from. 
I tried putting an event handler for 'focus' on the textarea, and for 'scroll' on the container, but was not able to detect the origin of the event in Chrome Dev Tools. Is there any way i can detect where the focus on the textarea is coming from?

Comment: Did you add the focus event handler using javascript/jQuery or in the Dev Tools? Is there an `autofocus` attribute on the textarea?

Comment: no autofocus attribute on the textarea. i added the focus event handler in javascript, i.e., in the code only. not in devtools

Comment: on more digging, it was the autofocus. please add that as an answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways to set the focus:

1. With an `autofocus` property. (see http://davidwalsh.name/autofocus)
2. With javascript/jQuery

If the focus is set using `autofocus` simply remove that attribute.

If it's set by javascript/jQuery you can try to set an "Event Listener Breakpoint" in the Webkit DevTools.

Go to the 'Sources" tab and on the right/bottom under "Event Listener Breakpoint" select Control -> focus. This should pause the execution and show you where the focus is being set.

See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners